# Android - Sliding fragments when click list item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm trying to implement the sliding animation to transit from fragment1 to fragment2, like [this image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106274374/slide.png).

Firstly, I tried to implement xml with set and translate, but I got RuntimeException "Unknown animator name translate".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
     <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0%p"
       android:toXDelta="-100%p"
       android:duration="500">
     </translate>
</set>
```

Secondly, I tried to solve problem by using a class that extends framelayout, and add "getXFraction" and "setXFraction" method, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235690/android-making-translations-and-objectanimator-on-the-same-xml-file)

```
public class SlidingFrameLayout extends FrameLayout
{
    private static final String TAG = SlidingFrameLayout.class.getName();
    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlidingFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public float getXFraction()
    {
        final int width = getWidth();  
        if(width != 0) return getX() / getWidth();  
        else return getX();  
    }

    public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
        final int width = getWidth();  
        setX((width > 0) ? (xFraction * width) : -9999);  
    }

    public float getYFraction()
    {
        final int height = getHeight();  
        if(height != 0) return getY() / getHeight(); else return getY();   
    }

    public void setYFraction(float yFraction) {
        final int height = getHeight();  
        setY((height > 0) ? (yFraction * height) : -9999);  
    }
}
```

But I still don't know How should I use SlidingFrameLayout?
Please help me. T___T

Answer (score 1):

You need to use objectAnimator instead of translate. Here's are some posts with examples: [Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments) and [Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

Comment: But objectAnimator can't config to slide from right of screen like 'android:toXDelta="-100%p"'

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the SlidingFrameLayout as the root view of the fragments you want to slide in your xml layout file, for example if your root view was a Relative Layout:

```
<com.company.appname.SlidingFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.company.appname.SlidingFrameLayout>
```

Then use an objectAnimator, for example for a slide out in right direction:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="xFraction"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1.0"/>
```