# How to use StateListAnimator?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#viewstate):

> The new StateListAnimator class lets you define animators that run
>   when the state of a view changes. The following example shows how to
>   define an StateListAnimator as an XML resource:

```
<!-- animate the translationZ property of a view when pressed --> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:duration="100"
        android:valueTo="2"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
        <!-- you could have other objectAnimator elements
             here for "x" and "y", or other properties -->
    </set>   
  </item>   
  <item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="true">
    <set>
      <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:duration="100"
        android:valueTo="2"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set> 
  </item> 
</selector>
```

However, it says nothing about how to actually *use* this xml file. There seems to be no method on the `Resources` class to get a `StateListAnimator`, and the `StateListAnimator` class does not provide any info either.

How can we use this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In *Android L* a new xml attribute has been added for *View* :

```
android:stateListAnimator   : Sets the state-based animator for the View.
```

Additionally for instantiating *StateListAnimator* object programmatically a new method :

```
loadStateListAnimator(Context context, int id)
```

has been added to *AnimatorInflater* .

These can be found on *Android L* developer preview documentation package.

Comment: For a code snippet, try StateListAnimator sla = AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(context, R.anim.my_anim); View.setStateListAnimator(sla);

Comment: Say, why does AppBarLayout have a default stateListAnimator ? When does it ever get changed? Which states does it have, by default?

Answer (score 15):

I use this code in java and works fine

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            crd.setStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(ctx,
                    R.drawable.card_smooth_shadow));
}
```

And my animator/card_smooth_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:valueTo="10dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</item>
<item
    android:state_pressed="false">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:duration="100"
            android:valueTo="2dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"/>
    </set>
</item>
```

**RESULT**

[image: result]

Comment: How do you have a ripple effect with animator?

Comment: @Dr. aNdRO It's not the `StateListAnimator` but to apply that effect to any view, in the layout use `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @TimKist that work's too, but main usage of StateListAnimator here is shadow effect . as you can see when we click (or hold) cardView the shadow increases

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Radesh. I was referring to the ripple effect Dr. aNdRO was asking about, not your answer. That was a good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Lets you define a number of Animators that will run on the attached View depending on the View's drawable state.

It can be defined in an XML file with the  element. Each State Animator is defined in a nested  element.

The new StateListAnimator class lets you define animators that run when the state of a view changes. The following example shows how to define an StateListAnimator as an XML resource:
https://indiacodinghub.blogspot.com/2021/01/how-to-use-statelistanimator.html