# How can I use setStateListAnimator programmatically to my checkbox?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a checkbox to which I want to set animation e.g. When user hit like checkbox it display animation. If I set it using xml it runs anim on the initial display, But I want the animation to run only when user check the check box. It is possible only if I set it programmatically.

What I have tried yet:-

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/_like_heart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_user_heart"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="false"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/enlarge" />
```

Is there any alternative that can support lower versions of android as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref : [How to use StateListAnimator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458615/how-to-use-statelistanimator)

In `Android L` a new xml attribute has been added for View :

`android:stateListAnimator   :` Sets the state-based animator for the View.
Additionally for instantiating StateListAnimator object `programmatically` a new method :

```
loadStateListAnimator(Context context, int id)
```

has been added to `AnimatorInflater` .

These can be found on Android L developer preview documentation package.

> Ex

```
StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(this, 
 R.anim.enlarg);
 yourCheckbox.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);
```

For More Investigation Please Visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator

Comment: I already made animator file, my question is how can I set it at run time?

Comment: i know that use loadStateList animatior mathod @Tac_1

Comment: yes that worked but I have to specify version for using it. like  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                                              StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(context, R.animator.scale);
Is there any way to support lower versions?                                                              holder.cbHeart.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator );
                                                          }
Is there any equivalent  way to support lower versions?

Comment: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)  because its added in API 21

Answer (score 0):

on your checkbox listener add this snippet

```
 StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(this, 
 R.anim.my_anim);
 yourCheckbox.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator );
```