# objectAnimator shows white background for fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

i am trying to implement slide in slide out animation for fragments.
animation is working fine but it shows some white color layout in between
how can i hide or remove that?

i referred to this post, but don't know exactly what has to be done
[Android - Making translations and objectAnimator on the same XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235690/android-making-translations-and-objectanimator-on-the-same-xml-file)

my slide-in-left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

calling like this in my fragment

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right,
                    R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left
                    );
```

any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Hours of searching and debugging...i finally found the answer!

you need to create your own custom class which extends framelayout and apply properties:)
hope it helps some one!