# While switching between fragment with animation white blank screen appear

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I have problem that when i am switching between fragments white screen is appear before new fragment appear i don't know what is problem

**Here is my animations**

**anim/fragment_slide_left_enter**

```
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

**anim/fragment_slide_left_exit**

```
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

**anim/fragment_slide_right_enter**

```
 <translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

**anim/fragment_slide_right_exit**

 <translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

**Here is my function which load fragments**

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean isShow, String key, String value,boolean isBack)
{
    bundle.putString(key,value);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
     fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (OldFragment != null) {
        Log.d("fragment--->","yes------");
        fragmentTransaction.detach(OldFragment);
    }
        if(isShow){
       //fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_left_enter,R.anim.fragment_slide_left_exit,R.anim.fragment_slide_right_enter,R.anim.fragment_slide_right_exit);
        }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ll_fragment,fragment, tag);
    if(isBack){
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    OldFragment=fragment;
}
```

Comment: Try to put window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)); on fragment, you can change your desired color

Comment: bt i don't want any color i need switch fragment from one to another with animation and i want to remove that blank screen @Divyang Panchal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339014/objectanimator-shows-white-background-for-fragments-in-android

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no @jlively i just remove animation and simply display fragment

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561523/remove-the-white-screen-a-slide-window-transition-creates-when-it-starts

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem and since all the solutions that came up were just setting the window background I wasn't really getting anywhere. Than I thought => let's just try to set the background of rootview in the fragment I'm pushing in to transparent.. And voila, this did the trick. So the rootview of the fragment that I'm pushing looks like this in xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

Comment: it doesnt work - comments must be at least 15 characters in length